# Can not show video (mp4 format) when developing a web app for samsung smart TV

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

I'm using the latest Samsung smart TV simulator and developing a very simple app for it: Play a video.

The code is show as below. The code is so simple that I can not find the root cause (can not play video). I verified it on mac safari and chrome web browser.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>basicexample</title>
</head>
<body background="http://icbd.tv/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/background.jpg">
    <video id="video" src="http://www.808.dk/pics/video/gizmo.mp4" autoplay="autoplay">Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How are you test your sample? you run it on TV, on Emulator or in Browser on TV? On what models you want support?

Comment: Only 2012 and 2013 emulators from SDK 4.0 Support `<video>` tag

Comment: yes, it declares it supports. Have you tested it on the simulator?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13234221/does-hmtl5-video-autoplay-work-on-samsung-smart-tv

Answer (score 0):

Samsung SDK does not support `autoplay` attribute. To play video you need to manualy start it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>basicexample</title>
</head>
<body onload="document.getElementById('video').play(1)" background="http://icbd.tv/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/background.jpg" >
    <video id="video" src="http://www.808.dk/pics/video/gizmo.mp4" autoplay="autoplay">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>
</body>
</html>
```

This code plays video on 2011-2013 Emulators. 2010 does not support `<video>` tag.